# Haskell returning list with hexadecimal value

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define the function "decToHex" which returns a list of chars that corresponds to the hexadecimal value of a given number. For example, 1128 = ['4','6','8']

This is my function

```
decToHex :: Int -> [Char]
list = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"]
listHexa = []
decToHex x
  | x < 16 = list !! x
  | otherwise = decToHex (x `div` 16) : ((list !! (x `mod` 16)) : listHexa)
```

But I get this error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
  Expected type: [Char]
    Actual type: [[Char]]
• In the expression:
    decToHex (x `div` 16) : ((list !! (x `mod` 16)) : listHexa)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `listHexa` for by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall asymmetric operator `:` adds an *element* to the left of a list, while symmetric operator `++` concatenates two lists.

Hence, for an expression that starts with:

```
decToHex (x `div` 16) :  ... whatever ...
```

the left operand of `:` is already a string, that is a list of Char's. So the type of the whole expression has to be `[[Char]]`. But this conflicts with your type signature for function `decToHex`, which says it returns just a `[Char]` simple list.

**Side note 1:** things are less confusing when the list of hexadecimal digits is called `hexDigits` rather than plain `list`.

**Side note 2:** in a division, if you need both the quotient and the remainder, it is more readable and more efficient to use function [divMod](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:divMod) rather than `div` and `mod` separately.

We thus have the following code:

```
hexDigits  = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"]

decToHex :: Int -> [Char]
decToHex x
    | x < 0      =  '-' : decToHex (-x)
    | x < 16     =  hexDigits !! x
    | otherwise  =  let  (q, r) = divMod x 16
                    in  (decToHex q)  ++  (hexDigits !! r)
```

**Side note 3:**

Just like everything else, lists are immutable in Haskell. This implies that operator `++` has to work by [*duplicating* its left operand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61956851/11282404). Hence, using `++` for recursion in such a way is very inefficient. You might want to find a way to use operator `:` as your main recursion engine instead. You will probably need a simpler `hexDigits` list like `"0123456789ABCDEF"` as mentioned in arrowd's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your `list` is of type `[String]`, because every letter there is a `String`. Instead, make it a list of `Char` by replacing double quotes with single ones.