# How can I add n whitespaces after a string with recursion in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, recursion, addition

For example a number (5) and a string (apple) is given, and the program drops (apple_____).
I want to do this with recursion. I tried this way:

```
add :: Integer -> [Char] -> [Char]
add 0 (x:xs) = (x:xs)
add i [] = add (i-1) [] ++ " "
add i (x:xs) = format (i-1) xs
```

Comment: why do you use `add i (x:xs) = format (i-1) xs`?

Comment: Something not universally understood by Haskell beginners: list operator `++` has to do its job by _duplicating_ its left side operand; explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61956851/11282404) for example. Hence, building a list or string by repeatedly appending one extra item at the _end_ of the list, as done in your code above, happens to be quadratically inefficient. The root cause is that Haskell lists/strings are immutable. Note that the code in Willem's answer below manages to avoid using operator `++` completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you want to add `0` spaces, you can return the given string (1); if the string is non-empty, you emit the first element of the string `x` and recurse on the tail of the string (2); finally if we reached the end of the string, and `i` is greater than `0`, we emit a space, and recurse with `i` one less than the given `i` (3):

```
add :: Integer -> String -> String
add i xs | i <= 0 = xs  -- (1)
add i (x:xs) = x : …    -- (2)
add i [] = ' ' : …      -- (3)
```

You here still need to fill in the `…` parts.